# How to check if an array contains Float::NAN

Tags: ruby, nan

I find this behavior rather strange

```
> [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', Float::NAN].include? Float::NAN
false
```

I tried this then and got surprised

```
> Float::NAN == Float::NAN
false
```

So, to check for `Float::NAN`, I had to resort to

```
> [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', Float::NAN].any? { |i| i.is_a?(Float) && i.nan? }
true
```

So,

1. Is there a better way to check for `Float::NAN` in an array?
2. Why is there such a weird behavior with `Float::NAN`?

Comment: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6726568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check, you can use:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', Float::NAN].any?{|item| item.respond_to?(:nan?) && item.nan?}
```

(or `try`, if you use Rails)

And as for *why*, take a look at [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values/1573715)

Comment: Excellent answer! Would this work `[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', Float::NAN].any? { |e| e != e } #=> true`? That is, are there any other Ruby objects `e` for which `e != 3 #=> true`?

Comment: Good idea, but I'm afraid it would considerably increase the wtf/loc ratio. :) BTW, I have no idea whether any other class redefined `==` this way.